# zabbix_get shows no return values

Tags: zabbix

I have this shell script `ordem2.sh`. It works fine when executed in the command line:

```
var="$( mysql -Ns -uzabbix -e 'select ordem from mon.vendas')"
echo $var
```

I add `UserParameter` in `/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf`

```
UserParameter=ordem2,/home/ordem2.sh
```

But when I try to get information from zabbix 2.0 using `zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -p 10050 -k "ordem2"`, it shows no return value. What is wrong with this script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue was fixed.

**step 1**

edit sudoers using `visudo` and for user `zabbix` add `/usr/bin/mysql`

example: `zabbix ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mysql,/usr/bin/nmap -O *`

**step 2**

Add sudo before mysql in the shell script:

```
var="$( sudo /usr/bin/mysql -Ns -uzabbix -e 'select ordem from mon.vendas')"
```

Now the user `zabbix` agent can execute `mysql`.

Alexandre Alves